# Django - Annotating Weighted AVG by Group

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've got the following model manager that operates on a SalesRecord:

```
def by_variety_and_date(self, start_date, end_date):
    return self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        "variety"
    ).annotate(
        qty_applied=Sum('qty_applied'),
        margin=Avg('margin')
    )
```

What I'd really like is for the `margin=Avg('margin')` to return a **weighted** average, based on `qty_applied`. Is there a way to do this with Django's annotate/aggregate queries? I've been experimenting with stringing .aggregate() to the end of this, but I still want the average per `variety` as described by this queryset.

The model in this case looks like this:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    margin = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=12)
    qty_applied = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    variety = models.ForeignKey(Variety, null=True)
    totals = Totals()
```

**EDIT**

This is what I finally ended up with. It's a bit wonky, but it does the trick.

```
def by_variety_and_date(self, start_date, end_date):
    return self.model.objects.filter(
        date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        "variety"
    ).annotate(
        qty_applied=Sum('qty_applied'),
        profit=Sum('profit'),
        cogs=Sum('cogs'),
        sales=Sum('value'),
        margin=Sum(
            (F('qty_applied')*F('margin')), output_field=FloatField()
        ) / Sum(
            'qty_applied', output_field=FloatField())
    )
```

I used the F objects as [@WTower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940098/wtower) suggested to multiply each object's `margin` by it's `qty_applied`, then wrapped the whole thing in a `Sum` and divided it by the `Sum` of the `qty_applied` of all objects in the group. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Wtower's answer is incorrect. The result is equivalent to `Sum(F('a'))`.

We need a `Sum()` in the denominator for this to work.

The example here provides a clearer example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505423/1960509

```
>>> from django.db.models import F, FloatField, Sum
>>> MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(
...    w_avg=Sum(F('a')*F('b'))/Sum(F('b')))
```

This result may be an `int` or `float` depending on input data. To coerce it to a float, you can use `FloatField` on each of the `Sum()` calls or call `float()` on the result

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`F()` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

```
>>> from django.db.models import F, FloatField, Sum
>>> MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(
...    w_avg=Sum((F('a')*F('b'))/F('b'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

More on aggregation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet).

Alternatively, you can use custom SQL (*not* recommended) or a custom method in the manager.

Comment: No custom SQL needed :). This is a custom manager method, btw.