# Weighted average from queryset - Django

Tags: python, django

How get the weighted average from queryset as quickly as possible. Is it possible without the use of loops. Below is an example.

My models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    weighted = models.IntegerField()
    day = models.IntegrField()
```

In my database, I have the following values ​​for day 1:

```
Object ID I: Price=100, weighted=12, day=1
Object ID II: Price=50, weighted=1, day=1
Object ID III: Price=75, weighted=3, day=1
```

how to calculate the weighted average for day one?

```
day_1_average_weighted = Product.objects.filter(day=1) ???how to get a weighted average - 71.88???
```

Comment: If you can use `numpy`, you could do `np.average([100, 50, 75], weights=[12, 1, 3])`

Comment: @cmbfast: but this will not calculate the weighted sum at the database side, which is usually more efficient, since it limits the "bandwidth" between the database and the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement this with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Product.objects.filter(day=1).aggregate(
    weighted_sum=Sum(F('weighted') * F('price')) / Sum('weighted')
)
```

This will return a dictionary with one item: `weighed_sum` will contain the weighted sum.

For example:

```
>>> Product.objects.create(weighted=9, price=2, day=1)
<Product: Product object (1)>
>>> Product.objects.create(weighted=1, price=5, day=1)
<Product: Product object (2)>
>>> Product.objects.filter(day=1).aggregate(
...     weighted_sum=Sum(F('weighted') * F('price')) / Sum('weighted')
... )
{'weighted_sum': Decimal('2.300000')}
```